# How to start an animation just once on an event in libGDX

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to show an explosion animation which i created using a few textureregions and created Animation `missileblastAnimation` from those textureregion like this -- >

```
 TextureRegion[] explosion = { explodemissile1, explodemissile2, explodemissile3, explodemissile4, explodemissile5, 
                 explodemissile6, explodemissile7,explodemissile8, explodemissile9, explodemissile10, explodemissile11, 
                 explodemissile12, explodemissile13, explodemissile14,explodemissile15, explodemissile16, explodemissile17, 
                 explodemissile18};
        missileblastAnimation = new Animation(0.1f, explosion);
        missileblastAnimation.setPlayMode(Animation.NORMAL);
```

I have this following code in the `render` method -- >
Note:-  **`explosionstarted`** is set to true when missile hits the ground

```
  if(explosionstarted){//check if the missile hits the ground to start explosion animation
       batcher.draw(AssetLoader.missileblastAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime),
                              100, 300-102, 50, 102);
      if(AssetLoader.missileblastAnimation.isAnimationFinished(runTime)){
     // i found that isAnimationFinished tells if animation is finished or not but i still cant understand the passing runTime thing               
          explosionstarted = false; //reset the boolean to make the animation stop drawing
        }
    }
```

Problem is the animation is not playing as it should i.e sometimes it plays too much fast . sometimes it skips first few frames and jumps to ending frames.
What is the right way to do this?
Is there any other way i can check if the animation is completed ?

Comment: Do you set the runTime to 0 when you start the animation, and then keep adding the delta value while the animation is running?

Comment: No i started adding delta to it when the game started so its having the value of the total time passed after game start.

Comment: Try setting runTime to 0 when you set explotionStarted to false, and only add delta to runTime when explosionStarted == true.

Comment: yes it works now :D Thanks a lot buddy can you explain wat was going wrong ?Just post it as answer with explanation i will accept it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start your animation you need to set the runTime to 0, and then add the delta value while the animation is running. 
The animation class uses the runTime variable to figure out which frame to return based on the frame duration you specify when you initiate the class.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I know of:

```
if (!animation.isAnimationFinished(timeElapsed)) {
   batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(timeElapsed), this.getX(), this.getY());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Game Development SE site. When submitting answers, remember that it helps to elaborate on posted code.